# Ordering of natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Show that it is possible to arrange the numbers 1, 2, . . . , n
in a row so that the average of any two of these numbers
never appears between them.

*Hint*: Show that it suffices
to prove this fact when n is a power of 2. Then use mathematical
induction to prove the result when n is not a power of 2.

This is a problem from Rosen's discrete mathematics book.

I tried to think of it this way:

---

Take any n,find its nearest power of 2,(say m)less than or equal to n,find the arrangement for 1,2,...m,then the rest of numbers m+1,....,n just fill in the gaps within the sequence 1,...,m in a certain way.

---

e.g.,Take n=12,nearest power of two less than or equal to n,is,8.So arrange 1,2,...,8 which gives 1,5,3,7,2,6,4,8.Now the numbers 9,10,11,12 just fills in the arranged sequence in a particular way.Its the last part I am struggling with. How exactly does the rest of the numbers fit in?
I may be wrong with the above approach,so please share your solution,in that case.

Comment: I believe the hint says to use induction when $n$ **is** a power of $2$, not "is not."

Comment: But I guess,first you have to prove that its sufficient to prove the result for powers of two! and then extend the same for the whole list!

Comment: When they say "prove is suffices to prove," they're saying "prove that if it's true for powers to $2$ then it's true for all numbers."  In all, the two parts of hint follow a general strategy that's often useful:  reduce things to a special case, then prove the special case.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: to reduce to powers of $2$, pick a power of $2$ greater than $n$. Then for the induction, note that if $n_1, \ldots, n_k$ is a sequence with the required property than so are $2n_1, \ldots, 2n_k$ and $2n_1 - 1, \ldots, 2n_k-1$, while the average of $2n_i$ and $2n_j - 1$ is not a natural number.

Answer (score 2):

Better for your example of $n=12$ to go to the next highest power of $2$, i.e. $16$, for the pattern from your induction $$1,9,5,13,3,11,7,15,2,10,6,14,4,12,8, 16$$ and then delete all values greater than $12$ to give $$1,9,5,3,11,7,2,10,6,4,12,8.$$ The same approach will work in general.

Comment: Nice suggestion!...Thank you! But how do I find the arrangement of the sequence 1,2,....n where n is the next higher power of 2,in the first place!

Comment: The pattern I thought you had found was to take the pattern for $1,\ldots,2^k$ and follow each number with the number $2^k$ higher to give the pattern for  $1,\ldots,2^{k+1}$.  So initially $1$, then $1,1+1$, i.e. $1,2$, then $1,1+2,2,2+2$ i.e. $1,3,2,4$, then $1,1+4,3,3+4,2,2+4,4,4+4$ i.e. $1,5,3,7,2,6,4,8$, etc.

Comment: Now I understand how to create the sequence. So a possible proof by induction would be:To prove:1,2,...$2^n$ can be arranged in such a way that ,avg of any 2 numbers never appear between them. Base case:n=1.gives 1,2 which is already arranged,so proved. Inductive step:P(k):Let us assume 1,2,...$2^k$ can be arranged in the above way. So now P(k+1):will give 1,2,...$2^k+1$, or 1,2,...$2^k$,$2^k$+1,...$2^k+1$. 1,2...,$2^k$ is solved by the hypothesis,now how do I prove this part $2^k$+1,...$2^k+1$ ?

Comment: If you take two numbers the whole list but from different halves, then their average will not be an integer so not in the whole list.  If you take two numbers from the same half but different quarters, then their average will have a different parity and so not in that half. And so on: e.g. if you take two numbers from the same quarter but different eighths, their average will not be in that quarter.

Comment: No matter how hard I try to understand this pattern I can't figure it out.  Is there anyway some can explain it to me?  1,9,5,13,3,11,7,15,2,10,6,14,4,12,8,16.  I'm missing something.  I've read the explanation but it makes no sense to me.@bandit_king28

Comment: @RyBoneCoder At the previous stage you have $1,5,3,7,2,6,4,8$.  Take each number followed by $8+$ that number to get  $1,9,\,5,13,\,3,11,\,7,15,\,2,10,\,6,14,\,4,12,\,8,16$

Comment: @Henry Thank you so much.  I starred at that for an hour and couldn't figure it out.  I'm working on a similar problem this week and find this question very helpful. So, 1,5,3,7,2,6,4,8 is easy to deal with and no matter what power of 2 I raise this to I can just do a similar algo and it will hold up?

Comment: @RyBoneCoder You do essentially the same thing at each step to give you the new  permutation of the positive intergers to the new power of $2$.  And you start from the very short list of $1$, which becomes $1,2$ and then $1,3,2,4$ and then $1,5,3,7,2,6,4,8$ and so on.